# Find replace, which wildcards to use

Tags: regex, ms-word, ms-office, wildcard

What wildcards do i make to remove this: " [21:11:48] Thijs: " and replace it to nothing.
What I tried:

```
[**:**:**] Thijs:
and also [0-9]
```

Didn't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\[[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\] Thijs:`

You needed to escape the brackets since they are a RegEx metacharacter. I also specified that there must be exactly two digits with `{2}`.